# Objective C: Create multiple UIPickerView with UITextFields programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a form screen. When creating a form screen, I want to add form elements.

Ex: I want to add multiple phone like this picture. When I press the Add button, I need to add in order.(The first line fixed.
Created initially.) How do I make the dynamic alignment. Every line I have to align the top.
[image]

Comment: can you explain more about  what do yo need  exactly  ?

Comment: I need to build this structure. When I press the Add button to add in this way, when I delete anyone of will realign others. So I need to make additions or deletions as dynamic in this area. 
I want to assign ID to each of these elements.

Answer (score 2):

to build this structure you need to 
1.add UITableView object to your main view controller ,
2. and for "add button" insert a bar Button item at navigation item . 
3.if you use dynamic tableview you can just update your data source and add cells dynamically .

plz tell me the result.

Comment: you can email me if you want to start creating the view step by step

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this is to use a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell.

As for the picker i worked on something similar that can be found here : https://github.com/jadfeitrouni/JFButtonPicker